# How to solve equation system

Tags: equation-solving

How to calculate $x,y,k$ in terms of constants $a$ and $b$ in the following equations in Mathematica:

```
4*y-k*2*x/a^2=0,
4*x-k*2*y/b^2=0,
x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2-1=0
```

Why doesn't the following command work? (I am new)

```
Solve[4*y-k*2*x/a^2=0&&4*x-k*2*y/b^2=0&&x^2/a^2+y^2/b^2-1=0,{x,y,k},reals]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many errors in your code:

1. it is `Reals` not `reals`
2. you have to write `==` instead of `=` (read [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/115443#115443) for example)
3. you need curl brackets (as Bob Hanlon points out, there is no need of brackets if `&&` is used).

The correct code is:

```
Solve[{4*y - k*2*x/a^2 == 0 && 4*x - k*2*y/b^2 == 0 && 
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, y, k}, Reals]
```

**EDIT** If you have to consider some assumptions, use the following code:

```
Assuming[{your assumptions},Simplify[Solve[{4*y - k*2*x/a^2 == 0 && 4*x - k*2*y/b^2 == 0 && 
   x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - 1 == 0}, {x, y, k}, Reals]]]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. How can we add to more conditions which are $x>0$ and $x>0$?

Comment: @mattiav27, you'd actually want to put `Simplify[]` within `Assuming[]` so that any assumptions set get accounted for in simplification.

Comment: Since `&&` is used, equations do not have to be inside brackets, Brackets are needed if the equations are separated by commas. First argument to `Solve` can include inequalities, e.g., `Solve[4*y - k*2*x/a^2 == 0 && 4*x - k*2*y/b^2 == 0 && 
  x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 - 1 == 0 && x > 0 && y > 0, {x, y, k}, Reals]`; however, `Assuming` is better since as @J.M.points out they are passed to `Simplify`.